# Using gradle with an Exec task when workingDir has white spaces

Tags: escaping, gradle, whitespace

I am following the [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) and I tried to create an Exec task:

```
task karmaTest(type:Exec) {

  // #1 workingDir project.projectDir;

  // #2 workingDir project.projectDir.canonicalPath;

  // #3 workingDir project.projectDir.absolutePath;

  // #4 workingDir project.projectDir.absolutePath.replace(" ", "\\ ");
  commandLine 'karma start --singleRun true --browsers PhantomJS src/test/js/config/karma.conf.js'
}
```

The task is really simple. It just needs to execute javascript tests using karma.

Output #1:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "karma start
>   --singleRun true --browsers PhantomJS src/test/js/config/karma.conf.js" (in directory
>   "/home/eianni/Br/Repositories
>   Ciao/git/workflowcobrand/wfc-services"): error=2, No such file or
>   directory

Output #2:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "karma start
>   --singleRun true --browsers PhantomJS src/test/js/config/karma.conf.js" (in directory
>   "/home/eianni/Br/Repositories
>   Ciao/git/workflowcobrand/wfc-services"): error=2, No such file or
>   directory

Output #3:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "karma start
>   --singleRun true --browsers PhantomJS src/test/js/config/karma.conf.js" (in directory
>   "/home/eianni/Br/Repositories
>   Ciao/git/workflowcobrand/wfc-services"): error=2, No such file or
>   directory

Output #4:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "karma start
>   --singleRun true --browsers PhantomJS src/test/js/config/karma.conf.js" (in directory
>   "/home/eianni/Br/Repositories\
>   Ciao/git/workflowcobrand/wfc-services"): error=2, No such file or
>   directory

As you can see I tried in different ways but I'm still getting the error. I don't think it's the white space since when I renamed If was getting the same error and I also removed `workingDir` (because the default from docs is `project.projectDir` but I'm still getting the error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation that you linked to, `commandLine` takes a list of command line arguments, not a single string holding the complete command line. The first item in the list is considered the executable. For convenience, you may want to keep a single String and split it with `tokenize()`:

```
commandLine 'karma start --singleRun true --browsers PhantomJS src/test/js/config/karma.conf.js'.tokenize()
```

Comment: Yes, I actually corrected it after a while. I'm not used to the syntax so I thought it was a string. Thanks mate.